# How to run DOM ready functions in jQuery when they have been loaded via AJAX?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My company has a web application built in ASP.NET and they have asked me to code up a widget for a dashboard page they already have. These widgets are custom user controls that are loaded dynamically at runtime. My problem is that I have some custom javascript that needs to run every time the widget is loaded.

```
$(function ()
{
    // Setup widget.
});
```

This works great when the dashboard page first loads. My DOM ready function runs and all is well. However, whenever a user moves around widgets on their dashboard all the widgets are in an update panel and they all reload using AJAX. DOM ready functions do not run when they are inserted into the page via AJAX.

Any suggestions for how to ensure this code runs every time the widget is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I get around this is to name the given event bidings when you define them initially on load. Then, in the callback function to the ajax unset these events, and set them all up again for the newly created dom elements.

Comment: My problem is that I don't have control over how the widget is loaded. I can only work within the confines of the widget unfortunately. If I could modify the ajax call I definitely would.

Comment: Ahhh, hmm. That is tricky. I can't say I have tried to do this before. Are iframes not an option? Maybe you can have those scripts run on hover rather than load? Would that work? Maybe you can have those initially run functions dynamically load scripts into the head of the page which in turn somehow listen for that ajax reshuffle event? I dunno if this makes everything easier or harder...

Comment: brilliant idea. I will give that a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the ASP.Net AJax pageLoad() function?

Explanation of how it differs to $(document).Ready() here -> http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Answer (score 0):

You could have each widget call the setup function after its HTML is written into the DOM.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm asking how to do? I've tried including a script that is not DOM ready wrapped at the bottom of the widget. That gets fired on page load, but not again when reloaded via ajax.

Comment: The DOM is ready ONCE - when the initial page is rendered. It doesn't stop being "ready" when there is a reflow or redraw. All you can do is query the DOM to see if your element is there before executing code against it.

Comment: I guess the point I'm trying to explain is that you cannot depend on "dom ready", you need to hook into something else. Perhaps you can poll the DOM for changes on a timer.

Comment: And I'm trying to explain that I am very aware that I cannot depend on dom ready. Hence the problem, I'm looking for suggested alternatives, not statements of the fact that I need an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

When you do your ajax call have return function execute your setup code

```
$.post(url, {/*data*/}, function() {
    // return function call
    // do setup code
});
```

EDIT:

Since you dont have control you could have a handler to intercept ajax calls:

```
$(#your-widget-area).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {

});
```

you can find the documentation here : http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: See comment on Hoatzin's answer. Sounds like without that control I might be screwed.